# jsPDF fontStyles not working in custom Font

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf-generation, jspdf

I have downloaded Calibri_bolditalic.ttf font and using it in jsPdf. In the genereted pdf, I can see font as Calibri but the font style appears to be normal. I want that to be appear in bold and italic font Styles.

This is my code: -

```
let doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
    doc.addImage(Header, "PNG", 20, 20, 550, 40, "header", "NONE", 0);

    doc.addFileToVFS(
      "./fonts/Calibri_bolditalic.ttf",
      "calibri_bolditalicbase64format"
    );
    doc.addFont("Calibri.ttf", "Calibri", "bolditalic");

    doc.setFont("Calibri", "bolditalic");
    doc.setFontSize(12);
    doc.setTextColor("#361755");
    doc.text("Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet", 20, 80);
```

ScreenShot of generated pdf:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per Documentation below is your api methods and params so you need to split italic to 2nd param & Bold to 3rd param

> doc.setFont(fontName, fontStyle, fontWeight) → {jsPDF}
>
> Param 1- fontName string   Font name or family. Example: "times".
>
> Param 2- fontStyle    string   Font style or variant. Example: "italic".
>
> Param 3- fontWeight   number | string  Weight of the Font. Example:
> "normal" | 400

```
doc.setFont("Calibri", "italic", "400")
```

[API Doc Ref image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUuj1.png)